# Why is XQuartz missing the "Preferences" popup window?

Tags: x11, xquartz

Help.

I installed this version of XQuartz 2.8.1 from here: https://www.xquartz.org/

When I run it, it starts up and shows up in my task bar BUT I am unable to find the "Preferences" menu.  Seems to be missing?   Anyone know why?

[image]

I need the Preferences menu so I can check the boxes to allow permissions for Docker application to use my desktop.    A few years ago I used XQuartz and it worked.   I also tried version 2.7.11, same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App preferences are available from the menu named the app’s name in the top left of the screen.

When the app is activated, the menus show for the app and include a menu named the app’s name, where the preferences are one of the options presented when clicking that. It would be very unusual and unexpected to place a link to preferences from the Dock icon — I’ve never seen any app do that.